# Copy values form array into target without Loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am using a function to extract numbers from string , then split it’s values into a range. 
I need **if possible** to insert the values into `Target` without Loop Target. 
Grateful for your help.

```
Dim arr
arr = Split(ExtractNumbers(str)) 'ExtractNumbers is a Function ,str is a string
 
For n = 0 To UBound(arr)
   Target.Offset(n) = arr(n)
Next n
```

Comment: `Target.Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)`. `Split` returns a 1D array, so use `Transpose` when writing to the sheet.

Comment: Transpose does have a limit of around 65k rows, but I assume it's appropriate for your setup.